# Possible issue in presentation of N² diagram with indexed inputs/outputs?

Tags: openmdao

When visualizing the structure of the circuit tutorial via an N² diagram, I noticed that implicit components with indexed inputs/outputs labelled using the pattern `x:y` (e.g. `I_out:0` of `n1`) do not display connections into the output of the block (in this case `V` of `n1`).
[image: N² diagram of circuit tutorial]

I understand that it is computing the residuals with the inputs and some initial "guess" to provide the output, so is this by design for `ImplicitComponent` because the connections are implicit? I tend to use the diagrams for debugging, and seeing no connections to the output makes it look unclear if it's connected, even though the inputs are fed into it and the code processes it via the residual equation correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in OpenMDAO 2.9.1, but has been fixed already on OpenMDAO master. So the next release, due out before the end of Feb 2020 (2.10) should have the issue fixed.

Comment: Thanks! On a similar note, I also noticed that mutated variables in components after the problem setup, which have no connections, appear in a "red" state. Is this presentation intended by design? I tend to get confused whether it's using the default value or the mutated value when looking at the diagram, although it can be verified by printing the variables.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "mutated" in this context. There was a bug related to the artificial splitting up of variables when there was a ":" in the name, so that those variables looked un-connected (red)  even if they were actually connected. That bug isn't showing up in your example --- the `I_out:` variables are being artificially split up there, but are showing as connected.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity; this is unrelated to the main question. When creating a component with a default input value having no connected inputs, the variable appears as red according to the legend (as per design, I assume). However, if you mutate the value of this variable after calling the ```.setup()``` method for a problem, the diagram doesn't really have any way of displaying this mutation of the variable from its default value unless you print it to check.